# Recommended organization chart tool

Tags: database, data-visualization, charts

I am looking for a tool which would display an org chart.

My company has a staff of about 300. I need a tool that will connect to a database, pull information from it, and display it on my company intranet.

Staff have metadata associated, and I would like to be able to filter on certain fields.

Nice to have: available as a mobile app.

Must be able to display staff photo.

I am looking at OrgChartPro, but any recommendations would be awesome.

What are the tools most popular in industry?

Does not have to be open-source, just not outrageously expensive.

Thanks!

Comment: There is Visio by Microsoft ( https://products.office.com/en-US/Visio/visio-pro-for-office-365-online-diagram-software?omkt=en-US) that can import data from a database and automatically create a chart. 13$ per month, though.

Comment: Visio is a little limited - One needs to reformat on each fresh import. Also am looking for good searching features...which that does not have.

Comment: What is the DBMS of your database, something like Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL, Postgress, or anything PDO compliant?